# How does the default xml namespace work in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

How is this url mapped to .NET namespaces? Can you give an example how to do the same thing for custom .NET classes/namespaces? Is it an attribute that has to be defined on the namespace itself?

Or is it a matter or using C# aliases as in?:

```
using alias = FullNamespace
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping is done using the [`XmlnsDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) attribute. For instance :

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Data")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media.Animation")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Input")]
```

(code from PresentationFramework.dll extracted with Reflector)

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't recommend it, because it could cause conflicts between your classes and those from the standard WPF namespaces