# Possible to use a URI as an XML namespace in WinRT XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, xml-namespaces, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

apparently XML namespace support got changed in WinRT's take on XAML. So, is there a way to use a URI as a namespace in WinRT? Example:

```
xmlns:mine="http://myuri"
```

and have the `mine` namespace point to one of my assemblies? I've seen how this is done in [Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517577/how-does-the-default-xml-namespace-work-in-xaml). Now how does it work in WinRT?

Answer (score 0):

[XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) is not available in WinRT XAML, but perhaps you could implement [IXamlMetadataProvider](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/03/07/Xaml-integration-with-WinRT-and-the-IXamlMetadataProvider-interface.aspx) and define [XmlnsDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xmlnsdefinition.aspx)s to achieve the same effects. I was just wondering about that yesterday. Apparently you can implement the interface and the XAML parser will use your implementation when parsing your XAML. If you check your obj folder you can see how VS automatically generates a XamlTypeInfo.g.cs file that is used to parse the XAML without using reflection. It might shed some light on how to implement your own version. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I've seen the XamlTypeInfo stuff, but that doesn't seem to reference IXamleMetaDataProvider at all.. and I really do not understand what it does (I work directly with IL, so I've been rewriting things in XamlTypeInfo for about 3 weeks now.. and I still know nearly nothing about what it actually does or how it works)

Comment: Ah, it just makes `App` the IXamlMetaDataProvider... I was looking in the _XamlTypeInfo namespace for it. One odd thing about it though is how does the WinRT itself work? I mean they use URIs for their namespaces, but the default GetXmlnsDefinitions just returns an empty array

Comment: No idea. I have not implemented the interface before, merely noticed it allows to declare a list of XmlnsDefinition objects and read that it is used instead of reflection when parsing XAML and instantiating objects, so I think it could work for you. I am just not sure where to implement the interface since App object already has an implementation generated. Perhaps a random control added to the tree would be fine, but it does not feel right...

Answer (score 0):

found some encouraging info at:
http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2013/05/30/Decoding-the-IXamlMetadataProvider-interface-Part-1

> So the auto-generated code automatically detected that my custom
>   library has a second metadata provider embedded, and injects it into
>   this list as well as the auto-generated one. So it looks like we
>   should be able to provide our own implementations, which I’ll get back
>   to later.

and at http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/03/07/Xaml-integration-with-WinRT-and-the-IXamlMetadataProvider-interface.aspx